# Most efficient way to handle variably sized UITableView Cells, and retrieve associated data efficiently

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hey all, would really appreciate some help with this - I am aiming at high efficiency w.r.t data fetches and memory usage.

I have a core data store, storing table of content items (tocEntity): article title, page number. A page can have multiple  articles, and page numbers can exist or not i.e. if you have a 5 page article starting on page 3, you won't have any t.o.c. entries for pages 4-7.

When I display the above in a table view, each cell displays all articles names for a page, so some cells will have a single article name, while others could have 10 (or more)

No problem getting the cells laid out fine, but I am interested in efficiently fetching the data only for what is currently needed for the table view (the way NSFetchedResultsController works) - problem is, there is not 1 core data entry per cell, but rather varying amounts. So if NSFetvhedResultsController would say (get me the data for cells 12-17) - this would not results in a single core data retrieval.

Any ideas how to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` retrieve all of the data into an `NSArray` then use this array in the `UITableView` DataSource methods instead of the live calls. If you want to refresh the data, repopulate the array from the data and call `reloadData` on the tableview.

Comment: This is how I am doing it, but it is not a memory-efficient solution at all, and not scalable - it is possible that only 1% of the total data could be displayed on the screen at 1 time...

Comment: Unfortunately the way the apple code works (as you have found) is that it calls the same methods LOTS of times when rendering. The only thing you could do is limit the number of rows and then detect scrolling and insert rows in the table etc but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that CoreData is faulted, which means even though you have your core data objects in an array, you are NOT holding the WHOLE object graph in memory, when you access a property on an object it faults which results in CoreData fetching that data, it is quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I'd recommend grouping all of these links in a table view section, rather than grouping them in a table view row. This is because variable height cells can reduce scrolling performance.

Comment: I considered this - but it will result in a table with many single-cell sections (more common than multi line ones), which will look pretty clumsy? Is there any way to get each section to join up with the previous one, i.e. have not gap between the sections?

Comment: I'm not clear on where the gap is you're referring to. If sections are a problem, you might try using an unindented row to represent a page, followed by indented rows that represent page links.

Comment: Are you iterating over the entire results array to group article names by page? If so, each object in the array is faluted when it's property is accessed. To improve performance, you'll need to determine a way to return the entities already sorted and grouped for display. In regards to sections, you can also return a custom view for table sections, which can include a disclosure triangle, etc.